# problem solving in website loading

Tags: plugins, phpmyadmin

```css
/*! elementor – v3.16.0 – 20-09-2023 */
.elementor-widget-image{text-align:center}.elementor-widget-image a{display:inline-block}.elemenhow tor-widget-image a img[src$=”.svg”]{width:48px}.elementor-widget-image img{vertical-align:middle;display:inline-block}
```

how to solve this error

Comment: What's the error? That's just a block of CSS. Are you saying that that's all you see on your site?

Comment: Please edit the question to include the error and some context, at the moment it's unclear what you're asking as it's a chunk of elementor CSS without explanation